# Windows 200x Server - User Group vs User privilege conflict

Tags: windows, privacy, active-directory

I have denied to a specific user to write on a file. Unfortunately this user is a member of a User Group which have the privilege to write on this file. So there is a conflict between User vs. User-Group privileges. Which one will prevail here?

Answer (score 7):

Explicit "Deny" permissions always take precedence over all other permissions (assuming canonical ACL ordering-- but that's probably a safe assumption). The permission denying the user "Write" permission will override any permission granting the user "Write" based on group membership.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Evan!
Also run a test and you are absolutely right. Question closed - All credits to Evan Anderson PS: Question moved here, so I couldnt log in with the same account.